# Why is authentication shared between webapps in iis?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, web-applications, settings

On a default web site in IIS I have 2 webapps, than have different pool, different name but **same** physical path.

If I go into one application and change for authentication settings for anonymous authentication to enable, exact settings is set to enable in another application and vice versa.

This happens only on one system. If I try to replicate problem on another system, the settings for authentication stay different for both applications.

Anyone knows why do I get this kind of behavior between two apps.

System info:

Windows Server 2012 R2

Version 6.2 (Build 9200)

IIS: 8.5.9600.16384

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Smash.

Comment: If there is no code involved then StackOverflow is not the right place.
Consider posting it to https://serverfault.com/ (another stack exchange website).

Comment: ok, I didn't know that.

Comment: Edit your question if you find new information. You should not post "answers" below as they aren't.

Comment: ok, didn't know that...i am new here..thanks for tips.

Answer (score -1):

I found out what was the problem. It had to do with feature delegation in IIS. I've set readonly feature delagation on anonymous authentication and that was it.